# Web Frontend for ASP Membership / User Management?

Tags: .net, asp.net, sharepoint

Is there any product out there that allows for the management of users using a standard asp.net membership database?
I'm looking for a web frontend user management system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used the [Community Kit for SharePoint Forms Based Authentication Solution](http://www.codeplex.com/CKS/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=17901) for this previously. There were issues but easily fixed and there's been newer releases since then. It worked really well. From the web site its features are:

- Membership request webpart (including CAPTCHA)
- Membership request list
- Login web part
- Recover Password web part
- Change Password web part
- User Management
- Role Management
- User Properties
- Automated Solution Deployment
- ULS Logging

Answer (score 1):

Kenneth,

You might want to check out the "SharePoint for Hosters" solution on CodePlex (http://sharepointhosters.codeplex.com/).  It contains a number of add-ins and enhancements for hosting SharePoint solutions, including WebParts that simplify the management of users in SQL Server databases.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

This project works for me:

http://fba.codeplex.com/

Of course when you are using an asp.net membership database you must use forms-based authentication. This project adds some nice features to the site collection root web for "manage fba users" and "manage fba roles."

It's all inline inside sharepoint.

-Oisin